# How to repetitively cycle through a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript object like so:

```
var object = [{ id: 1, title:"xyz" }, {id: 2, title: "abc"}, {id: 3, title: "sdfs"}];
```

Now what I want to do is go through the object such that it would read the first id and output "xyz", then pause for 5 seconds, then go through the second id and output "abc", pause for 5 seconds again then go through the third entry output "sdfs", pause for 5 seconds yet again and start all over from entry 1. I want this to go on indefinitely. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like homework. check out `for in` and `setTimeout`

Comment: And what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I want to know how you would iterate through the object from id 1 to id 3 and then repeat it from id 1 again and this should go on indefinitely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your basic recursive function:

```
function recursive(obj,idx) {
    if (obj[idx]) {
        alert(obj[idx].title);
       setTimeout(function(){recursive(obj,idx+1);}, 5000); // milliseconds
    };
};
recursive(myObject,0);
```

Or, to loop infinitely:

```
function recursive(obj,idx) {
    if (obj[idx]) {
        alert(obj[idx].title);
        setTimeout(function(){recursive(obj,idx+1);}, 5000); // milliseconds
    } else {
        recursive(obj,0);
    };
};
recursive(myObject,0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mezxw/

Comment: I took the liberty to fix this so it will carry on forever as in the question.

Comment: FYI, this isn't technically recursive because the second invocation of `recursive()` happens AFTER the first one has completed.  There is no accumulation of stack like there would be in a true recursive call.

Comment: @jfriend00 I bow to your superior CS pedantry. :-)

Comment: Strange, I didn't get any message informing me of your edit (which you usually do). I apologize.

Comment: Best and most effective answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = [{ id: 1, title:"xyz" }, {id: 2, title: "abc"}, {id: 3, title: "sdfs"}];

setTimeout(doNextObject, 5000);

var index = 0;
var length = object.length;

function doNextObject() {
    alert(object[index].title);

    index = ++index % length;
    setTimeout(doNextObject, 5000);
}
```

Comment: The `if` statement is unnecessary if you have `index = index++ % length;`. I think it should be `++index`, not `index++` or better `(index + 1)` so that we don't get into any undefined behaviour here.

Comment: thanks, I edited it. Had it there because first I didn't read that it's a circular loop and then forgot to remove.